# Javascript Selection remove tagnames of element and append content to ParentNode

Tags: javascript, dom, parent-child

I have this:

```
<p>
An 

<span class="item1">easyJet pilot</span> 

has told tourists that flying to

<span class="item2">Rhodes</span> 

is a “terrible idea” just minutes before taking off, it has 
been reported, as 

<span class="item3">wildfires spread across Greece</span> 

journalist Gwyn Loader, who was on the flight to the 
island to report for BBC Wales Welsh-language news programme 
Newyddion, said 

<span class="item4">eight passengers</span>

subsequently decided
to disembark, including a young boy who was in tears.

</p>
```

If I select a span or a part of a span, I would like to remove the span tagnames and append the selected text to the `parentNode`

For example, in , if I select "across", I would like it to be removed from the span and appended to the `parentNode`p. Therefore, it would create 2 spans as "wildfires spread" would be one and "Greece" would be a new one.

I am able to do it by using this:

```
const element = document.querySelector('span');
element.outerHTML = element.innerHTML
```

But this is removing the span elements one by one and not the one I could select using the mouse.

So I have tried to create a function:

```
function cleanup() {
            const selObj = window.getSelection();
            const selRange = selObj.getRangeAt(0);
            selRange.outerHTML = selRange.innerHTML
            
        }
```

But it is not working, although I have no error. The problem comes from the selection but I cannot figure out how to fix it.

What am I missing?

Thank you very much for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add event listener for the span and then replace the content like below.

```
document.querySelectorAll('span').forEach(sp => {
    sp.addEventListener('click', e => {
        e.target.outerHTML = e.target.innerHTML;
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue with your current approach is that you are trying to directly modify the **outerHTML** of the selected range, which is not supported. Instead, you should use the range object's **extractContents()** method to get the selected content as a document fragment, remove the  elements from that fragment, and then insert the modified fragment back into the document.

```
<p>
  An <span class="item1">easyJet pilot</span> has told tourists that flying to
  <span class="item2">Rhodes</span> is a “terrible idea” just minutes before taking off, it has been reported, as
  <span class="item3">wildfires spread across Greece</span> journalist Gwyn Loader, who was on the flight to the
  island to report for BBC Wales Welsh-language news programme Newyddion, said
  <span class="item4">eight passengers</span> subsequently decided to disembark, including a young boy who was in tears.
</p>

<script>
  function cleanup() {
    const selObj = window.getSelection();
    const selRange = selObj.getRangeAt(0);

    // Create a new div element to hold the selected content
    const tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
    tempDiv.appendChild(selRange.cloneContents());

    // Remove span tags from the selected content
    const spanElements = tempDiv.querySelectorAll('span');
    spanElements.forEach(span => {
      const textNode = document.createTextNode(span.textContent);
      span.parentNode.replaceChild(textNode, span);
    });

    // Insert the modified content back into the document
    selRange.deleteContents();
    selRange.insertNode(tempDiv);

    // Clear the selection
    selObj.removeAllRanges();
  }

  // Example: Call the cleanup function when a span is clicked
  const spans = document.querySelectorAll('span');
  spans.forEach(span => {
    span.addEventListener('click', cleanup);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but unfortunately it is creating a new div and not appending the content directly to the parent p. Thanks again as it helps me to better understand JS for other purposes

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT